# Knex simple UPDATE statement gives a syntax error

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

Working on a new project and encountered an issue with a simple UPDATE statement. Note that I am a Newbie to MySQL and Knex, and this issue should have a straightforward answer but apparently it doesn’t.
**The error**:

```
DBError: update `password_resets` set `used` = true, `updated_at` = ‘2022-03-18 00:03:12.666’ where `id` in 2 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘2’ at line 1
at wrapError (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/db-errors/lib/dbErrors.js:19:14)
 at handleExecuteError (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:1489:32)
 at QueryBuilder.execute (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:670:20)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
nativeError: Error: update `password_resets` set `used` = true, `updated_at` = ‘2022-03-18 00:03:12.666’ where `id` in 2 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘2’ at line 1
at Packet.asError (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:722:17)
at Query.execute (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
at Connection.handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at Socket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9) {
    code: ‘ER_PARSE_ERROR’,
    errno: 1064,
    sqlState: ‘42000’,
    sqlMessage: “You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘2’ at line 1”,
    sql: “update `password_resets` set `used` = true, `updated_at` = ‘2022-03-18 00:03:12.666’ where `id` in 2"
  },
  client: ‘mysql’
}
```

The line of code that produces the error:

```
const updatedReset = await PasswordReset.query(trx)
                .update({ used: true })
                .where(‘id’, reset.id)
```

**PasswordReset.js**

```
export class PasswordReset extends TimeStampModel {
    static get tableName() {
        return ‘password_resets’
    }
    id!: number
    userId!: number
    user?: User
    used!: boolean
    resetToken!: string
    expiresAt!: Date
    static relationMappings = () => ({
        user: {
            relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
            modelClass: User,
            join: {
                from: ‘password_resets.user_id’,
                to: ‘users.id’,
            },
        },
    })
}
```

It’s obvious that the SQL statement should have been

```
update `password_resets` set `used` = true, `updated_at` = ‘2022-03-18 00:03:12.666’ where `id` in (2);
```

I don’t have `whereIn` in the code used so I don’t even get it how it got `in` to begin with.
or

```
update `password_resets` set `used` = true, `updated_at` = ‘2022-03-18 00:03:12.666’ where `id` = 2;
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I know nothing of knex thought it was a sql question - but have you tried `whereIn`  in your const updatedReset?

Comment: I don't understand how why would `where` will result in an malformatted `where in` sql statement.
Also don't get why should I try `whereIn` when `where()` should already work 

Taken from the Knex docs: 

http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where
```knex('users').where('id', 1)```
Outputs:
`select * from users where id = 1```

Comment: Nor do I and you make that point very clearly,  nevertheless have you tried `whereIn`

Comment: I think it might be an issue with the environments, when in local both where and whereIn work perfectly; when in deployed sandbox we get that error with either one of them.

Comment: well that is useful for you to know - but nothing I/we can help with I'm afraid

Comment: Paul Maxwell,  I dug more into that and found the commit of the previous developer that actually fixed that exact problem and I simply concluded that he didn't deploy the latest working version to that specific environment. As far as git history everything is up to date, but the server code wasn't redeployed hence the bug. So neither knex or objection(the ORM) have a problem.